# Ubuntu GNOME 16.04: Shortcuts and function keys stop working after a while - why is that?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, function-keys

I switched from Windows to Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 a little while ago and noticed that frequently, at some point during a session my OS keyboard shortcuts (like CTRL+ALT+T to open up the Terminal, or pressing the volume buttons on my keyboard) just stop working.

Usually after a reboot, everything works fine - until it doesn't.

Any idea why that is and how to fix it?

Comment: happens to me as well on 14.04. it's not that they don't work, more that they are delayed for minutes.

Comment: potentially related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/906723/fn-media-keys-slow-delayed-on-ubuntu-gnome-17-04

Comment: it appears that there is a solution in https://askubuntu.com/questions/911946/terminal-appears-with-much-delay-when-shortcut-is-used