# Function keys delay under xfce

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, brightness, notification

After upgrading my xubuntu to 19.04 the use of my Brightness and Volume keys have a delay of 30+ sec and it looks similar to this topic: [Fn Media keys slow/delayed on ubuntu gnome 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906723/fn-media-keys-slow-delayed-on-ubuntu-gnome-17-04). I am using a HP Pavilion Laptop.

With ubuntu it works.

I think it is about the small pop-up message (Gnome's on-screen-display?), cause it does not pop up and every other fn-key not displaying a notification works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it via [this thread](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/notificatons-fehler/2/).
It was the OSDs conflicting somehow. Renaming the unwanted ones helped:

```
$ cd /usr/share/dbus-1/services
$ sudo mv org.freedesktop.Notifications.service org.freedesktop.Notifications.service.bak
$ sudo mv org.kde.plasma.Notifications.service org.kde.plasma.Notifications.service.bak
$ sudo mv org.mate.panel.applet.NotificationAreaAppletFactory.service org.mate.panel.applet.NotificationAreaAppletFactory.service.bak
```

Comment: Samesame here, on my Schenker Laptop. Thanks for sharing!