# Ubuntu 20.04 "hangs" when changing brightness level with keyboard

Tags: 20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my Dell Inspiron 5000 with Geforce MX 250.

Pressing the keys F6 and F7 decreases and increases brightness level, respectively.
And whenever doing so the OS hangs for ~5 seconds.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just for better bug tracking, I've added some links.

Related bugs (maybe duplicated):

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/2013255
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1892747
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-shell/+bug/1895486
- [Ubuntu 20.04 "hangs" when changing brightness level with keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242205/ubuntu-20-04-hangs-when-changing-brightness-level-with-keyboard)
- [Fn Media keys slow/delayed on ubuntu gnome 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906723/fn-media-keys-slow-delayed-on-ubuntu-gnome-17-04)

Upstream issues:

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1821
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/1279